In which cases I should use Task-returning methods in interfaces
I'm learning about clean code and now trying to practice it.
For example, I have repository interface which returns customers from database. In this case, because it's meant to access database, it should be async to avoid blocking. But what about other interfaces: providers, services, jobs?
Is there a general rule for it?

"Clean code" is a meaningless buzzword.

The hard and fast rule that works for me is to ask myself "does this method represent crossing an IO boundary?" - if so, then it will likely be an async Task-returning method. If not (i.e. it's an in-memory, CPU-bound operation) then it should be a synchronous method. Unfortunately if you're working with Stream objects then your work is cut-out for you because you'll want to support synchronous (non-async) methods over MemoryStream - but async methods over FileStream.
